# react-native unable to resolve module all the time

Tags: react-native

Here are some backgrounds:

**Windows 10**

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "orange",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Well, the app runs successfully. However, when I want to add modules, **any module**, it returns `unable to resolve xxx modules.` For example, below is when importing `react-navigation`:

[image]

but it installed successfully:

[image]

[image]

I've tried remove `node_modules` and reinstall. Also tried `react-native start --reset-cache`. Neighter works.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below command to install `react-navigation` to install.

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Restart your node packager if its already running.

Run your app with `react-native run-ios` for iOS, `react-native run-android` for android.

Rebuild your project in **Xcode** `Command + B` for iOS, in **Android Studio** `Command + F9`

Answer (score 0):

`npm` problem. Works with `yarn`.